# Can you legally refuse to accept out-of-state income after quitting a job?

Tags: united-states, income, state-income-tax

When you get income, you are required to pay taxes to a certain state.  What if you worked on a W2 job, then quit and moved out of state, and then the accounting department pays you some symbolic amount of pay into the following tax year, for whichever reason?

Would it be legal for them to do so, and can one legally refuse it to occur in a tax year where one has never worked for such company and in such state?  (For example, what about an Indiana-based employer?)

The problem is that the income goes into a new tax year, and one would have to file a tax return with the foreign state just because of someone in accounting not knowing how to do their job. Any way around that?

Comment: Most states have minimum requirements before forcing you to file a tax return. If the amounts are really symbolic - you just don't need to do anything, credit the tax withheld against your current state's tax and that's it

Comment: What if they misplace your final paycheck into the following tax year, or a part of it?

Comment: final paycheck is given on the final day. What do you mean by "misplace"?

Comment: @littleadv, not in every state -- in Indiana, it's given as per the regular pay period, it's not required to be given on the final day.  "Misplace" mean just that: the idiots in accounting not knowing what they're doing.

Comment: So can you describe the situation in more details then? As it is, your question doesn't make much sense. I've never heard of anyone misplacing paychecks, and I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. What is your concern exactly? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Is it so unheard of that some amount of money, that was supposed to have been included in a paycheck, is not actually included, and although the error is then fixed, one has to wait until the next pay period for the money to actually be transferred and the transfer accounted for?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Problem is that it goes into a new tax year, and one would have to file a tax return with the foreign state just because of someone in accounting not knowing how to do their job.  Any way around that?

Comment: Which brings me right back to my first comment. Besides, what's the problem with filing a return?

Answer (score 3):

Assume that you don't have direct deposit:

- The company will send you the check via mail.
- At the end of the year it will include that income on the tax form sent to the state and the federal government.
- The state and the IRS will then try to match the data from the company to individual tax forms.
- Even if you don't cash the check the IRS has already ruled that when you received the check that counts as income. This has come up on this site regarding is it the date on the check, the date it is received, or the date it is cashed.
- The company may also decide to review their list of un-cashed checks, and send a replacement check. They could do that on a regular basis or only once a year. They do this to reduce their liabilities.

Assume you have direct deposit:
 - The check was automatically cashed.
 - End of story.

This happens all the time. The last few days of the calendar year are paid in the following year. Of course it is a pain if that last check is the only one of the year.

Some states ignore the amount if you were only a resident for less than 1/2 a month. You will still have to file a form, and the amount is still income for your main state.